# How to set WPS Presentation the default Powerpoint program in Debian X11?

Tags: debian, x11, power-management, gsettings, wps-office

There is no menu option for the default powerpoint program in Details > Default Applications in Debian Linux, in Fig. 1. 
A terminal command and/or GUI tool is welcome for the task.

[image]

### Testing Stephen's oneliner

Commands and their outputs

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype test.ppt
application/wps-office.ppt

$ xdg-mime query default $(xdg-mime query filetype test.ppt)
wps-office-wpp.desktop
```

Testing setting up by the outptus the default ppt viewer

```
xdg-mime default wps-office-wpp.desktop \
application/wps-office.ppt
```

Output: no effect in opening .ppt files; other lines are not needed because VND and others are not in my system

OS: Debian 9.1 Linux
Powerpoint: WPS Presentation, currently LibreOffice presentation as default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a “default PowerPoint”; you need to define the default handler for the various MIME types associated with presentations. To do so, determine which `.desktop` file represents the program you wish to use, then (as your own user, not `root`) run

```
xdg-mime default your-program.desktop \
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation \
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template \
    application/vnd.sun.xml.impress \
    application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template \
    application/mspowerpoint \
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint \
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation \
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12 \
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template \
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12 \
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide \
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow \
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12 \
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-flat-xml \
    application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey
```

(filtering the list as appropriate). This will use `your-program` to open OpenDocument presentations, OpenOffice/LibreOffice presentations, PowerPoint presentations, and Keynote presentations.

You might need to add other MIME types; to determine which ones to use, run `xdg-mime query filetype your-file`, replacing `your-file` with the name of a file you want to configure. This will give you the MIME type to add to the list above.

If it’s correctly written, your chosen application’s `.desktop` file should have a MIME type entry listing the types it supports — you can use that instead of the above list.

Alternatively, since you’re using GNOME, you can right-click on your file in the file manager, select “Properties”, then the “Open With” tab, and choose the default application there. You’ll need to repeat that for all the different file types you want to open with WPS Presentation.

Comment: You don’t need to specify a path, the file needs to be installed properly (typically in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`) — `xdg-mime` will find it if it is. The command given in my answer is a one-liner, split across multiple lines for legibility (see the backslash at the end of each line but the last).

Comment: @Léo you shouldn’t need to restart. What does `xdg-mime query filetype yourfile` say? What does `xdg-mime query default $(xdg-mime query filetype yourfile)` say?

Comment: Alternatively, see my update to configure this using the GNOME GUI.

Comment: I expected you to replace `yourfile` with the name of the file you’re opening.

Comment: See my update; you’d need to add `application/wps-office.ppt` to the list of MIME types given to `xdg-mime default`.

Comment: No effect still with the one-liner. Please, see the body.

Comment: The alternative approach still works. I did not get the code work directly. It would be nice to understand why. Now, I am using *Wayland* so not sure if the proposal can work there. Can your first proposal work in *Wayland*?